# Relocate Line2D Java

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, line

I'm working with Java's Line2D.Float.

I'm trying to accomplish some sort of drag and drop for this shape.

I already get the selected Line2D object, I just need to figure out how to actually move it to the new coordinates.

I need something like this:

(`(Line2D)selectedShape).setLocation(newX, newY);`

selectedShape is a Shape Object, that's why I add the casting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#setLine%28java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D%29):

```
 void   setLine(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)

      Sets the location of the endpoints of this Line2D to the specified Point2D coordinates.
```